# Get ISBN number with regex

Tags: regex

ISBN numbers come with random dash positions

```
978-618-81543-7-7
9786-18-81-5437-7
97-86-18-81-5437-7
```

How could i get them every time without knowing dash positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete every `-` with your language of choice.

With Ruby :

```
"978-618-81543-7-7".delete('-')
#=> "9786188154377"
```

If you really want to use a regex :

```
"978-618-81543-7-7".gsub(/-/,'')
```

If you have multiple lines with isbns :

```
isbns = "978-618-81543-7-7
9786-18-81-5437-7
97-86-18-81-5437-7"

p isbns.scan(/\b[-\d]+\b/).map{|number_and_dash| number_and_dash.delete('-')}
#=> ["9786188154377", "9786188154377", "9786188154377"]
```

Comment: I don't think `.to_i` is a good idea - the ISBN "code" should stay a string. Use number types only for values you intend to do calculations with. In the case of ISBNs, it doesn't matter as much since no ISBN can start with a `0`, but it's generally a good habit to get into. Lots of examples out there with phone numbers, ZIP codes etc. getting mangled because of missing leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. I wouldn't use `to_i` for telephone numbers, for sure. Are there Zip codes which differ only by a leading zero?

Comment: I only know about Germany where new Zip codes with leading zeroes were introduced after reunification. Many old database systems (or even current Excel sheets) that used integer types for Zip numbers suddenly started to fail when the first East German address had to be retrieved...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy use of regex, google it to learn more. In Python:

```
import re
nums=re.findall('\d+',isbnstring)
```

This will give a list of the numbers. To join them to a string:

```
isbn=''.join(nums)
```

As per comments below, if you're working a file you could work it line by line:

```
with open(isbnfile) as desc:
    for isbnstring in desc:
        #Do the above and more.
```

As one example. There are a ton of ways to do this. I just realized from the command line `sed` is a good choice as well:

```
sed 's/-//g' isbnfile > newisbnfile
```

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple lines, as in the example : `'978618815437797861881543779786188154377'`

Comment: Well if using Python he would be reading line by line, or split prior or a ton of other solutions. I'm pretty sure this isn't the point though. I  upvoted you if that makes you feel better, since you gave a full answer.

Comment: You have a point. Feel free to mention it in your answer, and you'll get my vote too. (Thanks, BTW)

Comment: How cordial! done, and you made me think of another solution which is easy from the terminal, so thanks.